# Area of enclosed smooth curve is always irrational for rational dimensions

Tags: integration, area, irrational-numbers, curves, conjectures

I have the intuition that smooth curves that are enclosed cannot be possible in real world , so it must be the case that either the dimensions(parameters) that define the curve ( like the radius of circle) are irrational or  for real dimensions the area of the curve is irrational like for example for circle ([image]) and ellipse ([image]). Is there any such proof (for or against) for this conjecture for generic smooth enclosed curve ?.

Comment: What does being irrational have to do with the real world?

Comment: irrational numbers like pi are not possible to recreate in real , like for example drawing a perfect circle is not possible , it requires infinite atoms to draw.

Comment: Rational numbers are just as impossible.

Comment: Maybe so , I want you to concentrate on the original question , it is pointless to discuss on this , the focus point of this question is straight forward , do all smooth enclosed curves have irrational area given real parameters ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The area enclosed between a parabola $y=x^2$, $x$-axis, and vertical lines $x=p$ and $x=q$ for any rational numbers $p<q$ is $\int_p^q x^2=\frac {x^3}3\big|^q_p=\frac {q^3}3-\frac {p^3}3$, that is rational. The similar situation holds for any (necessarily smooth) curve of the form $y=P(x)$,  where $P$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients. If you wish to have a rational area completely enclosed by a smooth curve you can glue together several such parts as above. For instance, we can glue together four parabolic pieces $y=\pm \left(x^2-\frac 34\right)$,  $x=\left[-1/2, 1/2\right]$ and $x=\pm \left(y^2-\frac 34\right)$,  $y=\left[-1/2, 1/2\right]$.

Pythagoreans taught that natural numbers create the world base, so only their fractions, rational numbers are possible in the real word. Moreover, there is a legend, similar to ancient  Greek drama telling when one of them, Hipatius, found that the length of a diagonal of a square with unit sides is irrational, he was thrown down a ship into Mediterranean sea by other pythagoreans, and they decided to forget this theorem and never discover it again on death penalty.

Conic sections: circles, ellipses, parabolas are used in the classical mechanical world model. In particular, as trajectories of falling bodies or planets rotating around the Sun. Moreover, as far as I know, both Johannes Kepler and Isaac Newton who discovered and 
derived these motion laws, believed that they revealed God’s Universe construction plan.